# Is the set of fixed points of hyperbolic elements from $\mathrm{PSL}_{2}(A)$ a group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, cv.complex-variables

Given a subring $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, we can consider the set $\mathrm{PSL}_{2}(A)$ of elements in $\mathrm{PSL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ with entries in $A$ and the determinant of associated matrix is equal to one.

We define a hyperbolic elements from $\mathrm{PSL}_{2}(A)$ as elements
which the trace of the associated matrix is greater than two, in absolute value.

Let us denote the set of all fixed points of all hyperbolic elements from $\mathrm{PSL}_{2}(A)$ by $\mathcal{P}_{A}$. Notice that $\mathcal{P}_{A}\subseteq \mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$. If $A$ is a proper subring of $\mathbb{R}$, does it exist some result about $\mathcal{P}_{A}$ being a group?

Comment: When you construct $\mathcal P_A$ as a set of fixed points, on what is $\mathrm{PSL}_2(A)$ acting?  You say that $\mathcal P_A \subseteq \mathbb R$, but I don't know how to make $\mathrm{PSL}_2(A)$ act on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @LSpice I think the action is defined by the isomorphism of $PSL_2(R)$ to fractional linear transformations acting on $R \cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: If $A$ has infinite unit group (i.e. $A$ is not $\mathbb Z$) then $\infty$ is a fixed point of an hyperbolic element of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(A)$ so $\mathcal P_A$ is not contained in $\mathbb R$. On the other hand for $A  =\mathbb Z$ zero is not in $\mathcal P_A$ (as the group is discrete and zero is a parabolic fixed point).

Comment: Intersecting $\mathcal P_A$ with $\mathbb R$ does not give a ring in general, because it contains only quadratic elements over the trace field.

Comment: @abx I think you answered an older, wrong version of the comment. I thought a bit more and modified it. Your example is a better, more explicit way of saying what  it says now.

Comment: @Jean Raimbault: since you have deleted your comment, I deleted mine...

Comment: @JeanRaimbault, I fixed where $\mathcal{P}_{A}$ is contained. Thank you.

Comment: How could $\mathcal{P}_A$ be a group if it contains $\infty$?

Comment: @abx In case that the only units of $A$ are $\pm1$,  $\mathcal{P}_{A}$ does not contain $\infty$.

Comment: As noted above this is the case only if $A = \mathbb Z$, and then $\mathcal P_A$ is not a subring (as noted in the deleted comment, $\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3 \in \mathcal P_A$ but not $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$). So the answer to your question as asked is : never. It would help if you'd provide some context to explain what you are looking for exactly.

Comment: @JeanRaimbault it is not true that $A^\times$ is reduced to $\{\pm 1\}$ only if $A=\mathbf{Z}$. You seem to assume that $A$ is algebraic over $\mathbf{Q}$, which is not supposed. If $A=\mathbf{Z}[t]$ with $t$ transcendental then $A^\times=\{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: Right, I missed that.  I guess there are many finitely generated rings which have no units.